# How to exclude the support v4 library from the studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, dependencies, support-v4

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
  >   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/content/Loader$OnLoadCompleteListener.class

Code in build.gradle file

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    //compile project(':ActionBarSherlock-4.1.0')
    compile project(':GooglePlayServicesLibrary')
    compile files('libs/eventbus-2.4.0.jar')
    compile (project(':AndroidBetterPickers')){ exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    compile (project(':ZxingFragmentLib')){ exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    compile (project(':RobotoTextView')){ exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    compile (project(':PanesLibrary')){ exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    compile (project(':ShowCaseViewLibrary')){ exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    compile (project(':ActionBarSherlock-4.1.0')){ exclude module: 'support-v4' }



}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }



}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}



android {
    packagingOptions {

        exclude  'META-INF/maven/com.nineoldandroids/library/pom.xml'
        exclude  'META-INF/maven/com.nineoldandroids/library/pom.properties'
        exclude  'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'

    }



    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }




    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['.apt_generated','res','src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['.apt_generated','res','src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['.apt_generated','res','src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['.apt_generated','res','src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }




}
```

Comment: Let us see how your Gradle file looks like. The error points to a duplicate entry - indicating that you may have included something twice or more.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla Above is my build.gradle file.

Answer (score 8):

I've done it like this

```
dependencies {
    api('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0') {
       exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
 }
```

Comment: i have done the  same to all the libraries which as it support. but that couldn't  helped me.

Comment: note that the google play service api is [very big] (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) perhaps you need only some apis.
Back to you problem: try the command gradle dependencies. This will display project dependencies in a tree format.

Comment: +--- project :GooglePlayServicesLibrary
+--- project :AndroidBetterPickers
+--- project :ZxingFragmentLib
+--- project :RobotoTextView
+--- project :PanesLibrary
|    \--- project :ActionBarSherlock-4.1.0
+--- project :ShowCaseViewLibrary
\--- project :ActionBarSherlock-4.1.0                                                                               below is the tree for gradle dependencies

Comment: some of the libraries also use support v4  jar as a dependency in it. Was that the issue with the libraries?

Comment: With gradle dependencies you can identify which library use/require support v4. So if you done this you can exlude the support v4 on this library like you done it before e.g. compile (project(':GooglePlayServicesLibrary')) {exclude module: 'support-v4'}

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, after reset implementation to compile, it works fine, but I don't know why.....
maybe it's a bug of 'implementation'

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // compile project(':ActionBarSherlock-4.1.0')
    compile project(':GooglePlayServicesLibrary')
    compile files('libs/eventbus-2.4.0.jar')
    compile (project(':AndroidBetterPickers'))
    compile (project(':ZxingFragmentLib'))
    compile (project(':RobotoTextView'))
    compile (project(':PanesLibrary'))
    compile (project(':ShowCaseViewLibrary'))
    compile (project(':ActionBarSherlock-4.1.0'))
compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
```